# Ubuntu client could not connect to kerio on server 2003

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2003, kerio

We have Ubuntu on or network (AD). The server is Windows 2003 and Kerio Control is running as firewall on it.

All windows client are using Internet correctly but one Ubuntu client could not browse the Internet.

I get this message in browser when trying to connect :

```
Server not found.
Firefox can't find the server at server.company.local
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS problem to me. Is the Ubuntu machine using the same DNS servers that the Windows clients are?

Comment: Yes, all clients are using the same DNS server

Answer (score 0):

http vs. https?

Or did you perhaps define some access control like only allowing specific ip-ranges to access a service?